# Canasta Red-3 Up-Card

Tags: canasta

In the rules of Canasta, it says that if the up-card at the beginning of a round is a Red 3, then the discard pile is frozen.

But doesn't that go without saying? The discard pile is always frozen to everybody at the start of a round until someone goes down with the initial meld requirement.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It matters in the case that someone Melds without picking up the discard pile. In this case; that rule means that the discard pile is still frozen, even though it wouldn’t be if the up-card had not been a red 3.

Comment: Thanks Gendolkari. That makes sense. So are you saying that once a card gets placed on top of the Red-3, it's no longer frozen? I thought it acted like a Wild card and stays frozen. One other quick question while I've got you... If my partner has a Canasta, but I haven't played a card yet, can I "go out concealed" without a Canasta of my own?

Comment: @MylesMarkson No, the red 3 goes sideways just like a wild card would; so it stays frozen until someone picks up the discard pile. If it were only frozen for the very first turn, then you would be right that the rule would make no sense.

Comment: @MylesMarkson Please create a new/separate question for your other question.

Comment: You're a good man Gendo! It's good to have a friend who will help me with all of my Canasta questions. I'm a newbie!

Comment: @MylesMarkson As a friendly reminder if this answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted to show users that it helped and to show thanks to Gendolkari for providing the answer.